# How to get the result of an "EXEC storedProcedure()" in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Don't ask me why, but I want put in an sqlCommand object something like this:

```
sqlConnection a = new sqlConection(...);
sqlCommand b = new sqlCommand("EXEC storedProcedure()", a);
sqlDataAdapter c = new sqlDataAdapter(b);
DataTable d = new DataTable();
c.Fill(d);
```

So, when the stored procedure makes an insert the row is successfully added but however the code throws an Exception.

I know exist an sqlCommand.CommandType specifically for stored procedures but my architecture need it made in this way.

Comment: what exception does it throws please mention error too. Their no relation of your architecture with C# syntax. You can modify your architecture but not the syntax or methodology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the adapter "SelectCommand" property instead

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC storedProcedure()", a);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; //set command property
//..
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd; //set adapter command for select query
```

and your command type must be `CommandType.StoredProcedure` to exec SP and your architecture don't need this? simply ask him for a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax is off.

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx :

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
DECLARE @CheckDate datetime;
SET @CheckDate = GETDATE();
EXEC dbo.uspGetWhereUsedProductID 819, @CheckDate;
GO
```

So your code should be:

```
new sqlCommand("EXEC storedProcedure", a);
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are many ways to do the same thing, there are some things that work best when you do them the way the framework suggests.

In this case there are several things that can happen when you run the stored procedure, depending on which procedure it is.  It might return a set of row, or several sets of rows, or nothing at all.  There are already things we can do to handle all those situations, courtesy of the .NET framework.

Here's some extension code I've used in the past for any SP that is returning one or more rowsets:

```
public static DataSet ExecuteStoredProcedure(this SqlConnection connection, string SPName, params object[] parameters)
{
    using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = SPName;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;

        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Open();

        SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
        int index = 1;
        foreach (object p in parameters)
        {
            if (index >= cmd.Parameters.Count)
                break;
            cmd.Parameters[index++].Value = (p == null ? DBNull.Value : p);
        }

        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataSet res = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(res);

            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

Handling non-rowset return values and output parameters takes a bit more work, but this will do for your immediate needs:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection("some connection string");
DataSet ds = conn.ExecuteStoredProcedure("storedProcedure");
DataTable d = ds == null ? null : ds.Tables.Length < 1 ? null : ds.Tables[0];
```